# Buoyant Force Location

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram, buoyancy

Say you have a wood hinged then submerged in a liquid, the wood will move due to the buoyant force and becomes inclined in a certain angle. Like in the image below.

[image]

Where should I put the buoyant force? Is it just in the middle of the length of the submerged portion or in the center of mass of both the rectangle and triangle portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buoyant force acts at the "volumetric center of mass" of the submerged volume - so you include both the rectangle and triangle portion. It is indicated as the striped area in this picture:

[image]